# How to make website status available to all platforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

Recently, a project came my way with requirements to ... 
1. Build a C# console app that continuously checks website availability.
2. Save website status somewhere so that different platforms can access the status.

The console app is completed but I'm wrestling with where I should save the status. I'm thinking a SQL record.

How would you handle where you save the status so that it's extensible, flexible and available for x number of frameworks or platforms?

UPDATE: Looks like I go with DB storage with a RESTful service. I also save the status to an xml file as a fallback to service being down.

Comment: What do you mean by "different platforms"?

Comment: I vote for database solution (SQL)

Comment: You can use a database or a simple server (TCP)

Comment: @ruben..anyone of these..http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform

Comment: You could always just sign up for pingdom or monastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The availability of the web-sites could be POSTed to a second web *service* which returned a JSON/Xml result on the availability of said website(s).  This pretty much means *any* platform/language that is capable of making a web-service call can check the availability of the web site(s).

Admittedly, this does give a single point of failure (the status web service), but inevitably you'll end up with that kind of thing anyway unless you want to start having fail-over web services, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a webservice, and you probably will need to open less unusual ports on firewall to connect to a HTTP server than to connect a SQL Server database. You can also extend that service layer to add business rules more easily than at database level.

Answer (score 1):

You could save it as XML, which is platform independent. And then to share it, you could use a web server and publish it there. It seems ironic to share website availability on an other website but just as websites, other type of servers/services can have downtime also.

Comment: I like the XML solution because its static. Even if status hasnt been updated, there's still a last known status.

Comment: @foxtrotZulu, whether you use an xml file or a database, the "last known status" will still be there - even if it hasn't been updated.

Comment: You are right Moo-Juice, but I still prefer XML for this lightweight job! :)

Comment: @moo-juice ..yes that is if DB is not down..was thinking XML is the last resort because IO is pretty stable compared to a connection somewhere..:)

Answer (score 1):

I guess webservice is the best option. Just expose a restful api to get a simple Json response with the server status. Fast and resources cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel. Sign up for [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com), [Montastic](http://www.montastic.com/), [AlertBot](http://www.alertbot.com/), or one of the plethora of other pre-existing services that will do this for you.

But, if you really must, a database table would be fine.

Comment: Those services look great but i failed to mention that my solution must be internal. Working in a highly secure environment with proprietary data means that I cant allow access to an external server and my solution must be free. I like these though!